# Writing a line in a file when finding a keyword (without repeating)

Tags: python

I am trying to make a function which writes a line when it finds some text inside a file. Example:

Suppose i have "my_file.txt":

```
hello
friend
hello
brian
hello
kashmir  
Donald
```

I need "my_file.txt" to be:

```
hello
friend 
hello
friend
brian
hello
kashmir
Donald
```

I need that, if the script is applied again, the input and the output be the same, it is:

```
hello
friend 
hello
friend
brian
hello
kashmir
Donald
```

The **first problem** is that i want it to write "friend" not the first time it finds "hello" but the second. Here is what i have been trying, but i don't know if the idea is right. 
Any help?

```
def writing_line(namefilein):
    print namefilein
    filein=open(namefilein, "rw")
    tag="intro"
    filein.read()
    for line in filein:
        if tag=="second" or tag=="coord":
            try:
                filein.write("\n\n %s" %(friend))
                print line
            except:
                if tag=="coord":    
                    tag="end"
                else:
                    tag="coord"

        if "           hello" in line:
            if tag=="intro":
                tag="first"
            elif tag=="first":
                tag="second"
    filein.close()
```

The algorithm looks up for the word "hello", only the second time it finds the word it writes "friend" two lines after "hello".

Comment: Would this still be a valid question if you weren't reading/writing files? I think they are a distraction. See how to create a [mcve].

Comment: If `['hello', 'friend', 'hello']` becomes `['hello', 'friend', 'hello', 'friend']`, what does `['hello', 'friend', 'friend']` become?  What about `['hello', 'hello', 'hello']`?  Also `['red', 'white', 'blue', 'red']`?  (Data represented as lists instead of files, but algorithm should be the same.)  Please explain the algorithm.

Comment: I only have a sequence like ['hello','friend','hello']

Comment: You wrote """The algorithm looks up for the word "hello", only the second time it finds the word it writes "friend" two lines after "hello".""".  So `['hello', 'x', 'hello', 'y', 'z']` should be what?  `['hello', 'x', 'hello', 'y', 'friend', 'z']` (inserted before 2nd item after 'hello') or `['hello', 'x', 'hello', 'y', 'friend']` (replaced 2nd item after 'hello') or `['hello', 'x', 'hello', 'y', 'z', 'friend']` (inserted after 2nd item after 'hello')`?

Comment: @santimirandarp kindly add more  output as example to your output file!

Comment: Also, if there are five 'hello' in your file, do you only care about the second one?  If no, what is the rule about the 3rd and the 4th etc.?

Comment: The script i wrote is only a tentative one. If "hello" appears 20 times, i need to be replaced only the second one.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
from itertools import tee, izip_longest

def f(lines):
    new_lines = []
    lines_it, next_lines_it = tee(lines)
    next(next_lines_it) # advance iterator to second item
    h_count = 0
    for line, next_line in izip_longest(lines_it, next_lines_it):
        new_lines.append(line)
        if line == 'hello':
            h_count += 1
            if h_count == 2 and next_line != 'friend':
                new_lines.append('friend')
    return new_lines
```

Some examples:

```
>>> f(['hello'])
['hello']
>>> f(['hello', 'hello'])
['hello', 'hello', 'friend']
>>> f(['hello', 'hello', 'hello'])
['hello', 'hello', 'friend', 'hello']
>>> f(['hello', 'hello', 'friend', 'hello'])
['hello', 'hello', 'friend', 'hello']
>>> f(['hello', 'friend', 'hello', 'hello'])
['hello', 'friend', 'hello', 'friend', 'hello']
```

Here it is rewritten to work with filenames:

```
from itertools import tee, izip_longest

def f(infilename, outfilename):
    with open(infilename, 'r') as infile, open(outfilename, 'w') as outfile:
        lines_it, next_lines_it = tee(infile)
        next(next_lines_it) # advance iterator to next line
        h_count = 0
        for line, next_line in izip_longest(lines_it, next_lines_it):
            outfile.write(line)
            if line == 'hello\n':
                h_count += 1
                if h_count == 2 and next_line != 'friend\n':
                    outfile.write('friend\n')
```

Answer (score 0):

Probably not the most efficient but regardless you could read the file into a list like so, and after you modify the list with some logic to insert `friend` after all the `hello`'s that do not have `friend` immediately following. You can write the list back to the original file:

```
with open("data.txt") as f:
    content = f.readlines()

content = [x.strip() for x in content]

for idx, val in enumerate(content):
    if content[idx] == "hello" and idx != len(content) - 1:
        if content [idx + 1] != "friend":
            content.insert(idx + 1, "friend")
    elif content[idx] == "hello":
        content.insert(len(content), "friend")

f = open("data.txt", 'w')
for item in content:
    f.write("%s\n" % item)
```

**Original data.txt:**

```
hello
friend
hello
hello
hello
```

**data.txt after:**

```
hello
friend
hello
friend
hello
friend
hello
friend
```